# How to calculate Aspect Ratio of images in PHP

Tags: php

How do I find the lowest divisors from the width and height of an image. ie: 16:9.  I have provided an answer but Im sure there are much better ways to do this.  Can anyone provide advice on how to optimise this function?

Comment: The new meta: Preemptively answering questions

Comment: FYI, you are allowed to post a question and self-answer.  Answers themselves should not be posted as questions.

Comment: IMHO: if you already know the answer to your question put it on your blog/github/etc, not SO.

Comment: Also, don't declare functions inside of other functions.

Comment: Just to clarify that - you're allowed to post answers to your own questions, but posting a question *that you already know the answer to* is not what this site is for.

Comment: ok, I will rephrase...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
  function getAspectRatio($width, $height) {

    $ratio = [$width, $height];

    for ($x = $ratio[1]; $x > 1; $x--) {
      if (($ratio[0] % $x) == 0 && ($ratio[1] % $x) == 0) {
        $ratio = [$ratio[0] / $x, $ratio[1] / $x];
      }
    }

    return implode('/', $ratio);
  }
```

And testing it returns the following:

```
var_dump(getAspectRatio(600, 400)); // Returns 3/2
var_dump(getAspectRatio(640, 480)); // Returns 4/3
var_dump(getAspectRatio(1920, 1080)); // Returns 16/9
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for finding the lowest divisors for height and width of an image and returning the Aspect (ie: 16:9) and the ratio as a decimal (ie: 1.777778).

```
$width = 555;
$height = 888;

$ratio = getAspectRatio($width, $height);

print_r($ratio);

function getAspectRatio($width, $height) {

    function getDivisorList($px) {
        $dlist = [];
        $i = 1;
        while($px / $i >= 1) {
            if($px % $i == 0) {
                $div = $px / $i;
                $dlist[$div] = $px / $div;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $dlist;
    }

    $wx = getDivisorList($width);
    $hx = getDivisorList($height);

    $aspect = '';
    $ratio = 0;

    foreach($wx as $div => $num) {
        if(isset($hx[$div])) {
            $aspect = $num.":".$hx[$div];
            $ratio = $num / $hx[$div];
            break;
        }
    }

    return array('aspect'=>$aspect, 'ratio'=>$ratio);
}
```

this returns Array("aspect"=>"5:8", "ratio"=>0.625)

Comment: Instead of brute-forcing it you should try using prime factorization instead.

Comment: can you provide an example of prime factorization for this?